# The method '>' was called on null, on a function call

Tags: flutter, dart

i have function called total() with optional parameters, on first future builder its working fine with passing the argument ,but on second its throwing EXCEPTION,
**Note:** I already assign the variable subtotal to te text widget first,,but it is returning 0 because function is on future type ,variable is assigning before.

```
total({int position1, int length1}){


                        for (int i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
                        if (i == 0){
                          _subTotal =0;
                        }
                        _subTotal = _subTotal + position1;

                      }
                      return _subTotal;
                   }
```

below code is printing correctly

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 0, 10.0, 70),

        child: FutureBuilder<List>(
          future: db.getAllUsers(),
          initialData: List(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return snapshot.hasData
                ? ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                      final item = snapshot.data[position];


                         int position2 =    int.parse(User.fromMap(snapshot.data[position]).price);
                         int length2 = snapshot.data.length;


                   total(position1:position2, length1 :length2);

                      print('toatl is $_subTotal');
```

problem is calling this function here assiging the value to the text widget

```
 bottomSheet: Card(
        elevation: 4.0,
        child: Container(

          child: ListView(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: <Widget>[
SizedBox(height: 10.0),

              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10,5,5,5),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "Total",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 13,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          ),
                        ),



               FutureBuilder(

                **future: total(),**  the problem is here
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if(snapshot.hasData){
                    return Text(
                      snapshot.data.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                          ),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    );
                  }
                  return Container();
                }
              ),
```

this is my terminal issue

```
 ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (30282): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building CartScreen(dirty, state:
I/flutter (30282): _CartScreenState#39fc0):
I/flutter (30282): The method '>' was called on null.
I/flutter (30282): Receiver: null
I/flutter (30282): Tried calling: >(0)
```

Comment: What do you expect to get from `total()` with no parameters ?

Comment: @AugustinR return the value of variable subtotal ,which is assigned in above code when i called the total function with parameters

Comment: i just want to assign the subtotal value to the text widget in the bottom ,but i don't know how to do it ,if i assign the variable directly the it returns 0 for the first time ,because the value to subtotal is assigning in futureBuilder

Comment: Have you checked if `int position1` and `int length1` have values before using it in `total()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try total function like this

```
total({int position1=0, int length1=0}) {

  for (int i = 0; i < length1; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
      _subTotal = 0;
    }
    _subTotal = _subTotal + position1;
  }
  return _subTotal;
}
```

provide default values to the parameters

Comment: tried your soloution but this exception accur
The following assertion was thrown building CartScreen(dirty, state: _CartScreenState#3bc17):
I/flutter (17723): type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'Future<dynamic>'

Comment: why you require a future builder there?

Comment: ok if i do this instead of future builder,  Text("$_subTotal"   ),  then after opening the app subtotal will be zero ,because total function is assigned value in future builder ,

Comment: are you using the total in list ?

Comment: i am assigning the price from all list items into total which will be a bottom text not included in listview

Comment: then you can use a set state method to get that value

Comment: i am new to flutter i do not know how to use set state in textWidget or how to do that , can you help me.

Comment: [Flutter docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/interactive) have this tutorial about `stateless` and `stateful` widget in which the usage of `setState` was being discussed.